# Rails regex validation failing in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec

I am trying to write and test a regex valiation which allows only for a sequence of paired integers, in the format

```
n,n n,n
```

where n is any integer not beginning with zero and pairs are space separated. There may be a single pair or the field may also be empty.

So with this data, it should give 2 errors

```
12,2 11,2 aa 111,11,11
```

- error 1: the 'aa'
- error 2: the triplet (111,11,11)

In my Rails model I have this

```
validates_format_of :sequence_excluded_region, :sequence_included_region, 
                  with: /[0-9]*,[0-9] /, allow_blank: true
```

In my Rspec model test I have this

```
 it 'is invalid with alphanumeric SEQUENCE_INCLUDED_REGION' do
    expect(DesignSetting.create!(sequence_included_region: '12,2 11,2 aa 111,11,11')).to have(1).errors_on(:sequence_included_region)                  
 end
```

The test fails, as the regex does not find the errors, or perhaps I am calling the test incorrectly.

```
Failures:

  1) DesignSetting is invalid with alphanumeric SEQUENCE_INCLUDED_REGION
     Failure/Error: expect(DesignSetting.create!(sequence_included_region: '12,2 11,2 aa 111,11,11')).to have(2).errors_on(:sequence_included_region)
       expected 2 errors on :sequence_included_region, got 0
     # ./spec/models/design_setting_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regex

Your regex matches a single pair followed by a space *anywhere* in the string.

```
'12,2 11,2 aa 111,11,11 13,3'.scan /[0-9]*,[0-9] /
=> ["12,2 ", "11,2 "]
```

So any string with one valid pair followed by a space will be valid. Also a single pair would fail `3,4` as there is no space.

A regex that would validate the entire string:

```
positive_int = /[1-9][0-9]*/
pair = /#{positive_int},#{positive_int}/

re_validate = /
  \A                  # Start of string
  #{pair}             # Must have one number pair. 
  (?:\s#{pair})*      # Can be followed by any number of pairs with a space delimiter
  \z                  # End of string (no newline)
/x
```

#### Validators

I don't use rails much but it seems like you are expecting too much from a simple regex validator for it to parse out the individual error components from a string for you.

If you split the variable up by space and then validated each element of the array you could get that detail for each field.

```
'12,2 11,2 aa 111,11,11 13,3'.split(' ').reject{|f| f =~ /^[1-9][0-9]*,[1-9][0-9]*$/ }
```

You can put something like that into a custom validator class using [`validates_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-validates_with) which you can then have direct control of your [errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) with...

```
class RegionValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.sequence_included_region.split(' ').reject{|f| f =~ /^[1-9][0-9]*,[1-9][0-9]*$/ }.each do |err|
      record.errors[sequence_included_region] << "bad region field [#{err}]"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\s|^)\d+,\d+(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.The left string split by  are your errors.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/22

Comment: The regex is working, but so is the old one. Perhaps this is a Rspec issue.